# How to delete some duplicate rows from 1 table matching to other table

Tags: java, php, mysql, sql, duplicates

DELETE FROM `final` WHERE  rajuvas.`final`.`accession` = rajuvas.journal.`accession`

we have some common data in both table named final and journal now i want to delete those entries in final table which are there in journal table. We have 1 field common in these tables 'accession'. for example if accession 18572 is in both tables then i want that Final table record consisting of accession 18572 should be deleted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
DELETE final 
   FROM final 
   LEFT JOIN journal ON final.accession=journal.accession 
   WHERE journal.accession IS NOT NULL;
```

Or this

```
DELETE FROM final 
   USING final, journal 
   WHERE final.accession=journal.accession;
```

`final` - table where rows will be deleted

`journal` - table to check records exist

Comment: but it deleted journal rows :(

Comment: updated and first both worked sorry i had some problem in database before thanks

Comment: On the top of my answer in left corner there is a check button. Press it.

Answer (score 0):

You can just drop that table you don't want. try this sript  DROP TABLE  database_name.table_name;"final"

Answer (score 0):

Alternative:

```
DELETE FROM final f WHERE exists(select accession from rajuvas.journal j where j.accession = f.accession)
```